# White output dialog box in Fortran trouble with reading file

Tags: fortran

I am trying to read a file `cs251_1.dat` in Fortran and then trying to create a new file using the data from `cs251_1.dat`. The file `cs251_1.dat` was written by another Fortran program and the data inside this file is two spaces followed by a three digit number followed by two spaces with a total of four numbers on a line. However, I get the following error

```
C:\Users\Cornelius\Documents\~Source5.f:3:   
open(5, File = 'C:cs251_1.dat')  
1
C:\Users\Cornelius\Documents\~Source5.f:6: (continued): 
Integer A  
2  
Statement at (2) invalid in context established by statement at (1)
```

This is the program:

```
      open(5, File = 'C:cs251_1.dat')
      open(6, File = 'C:cs251_2.out')

      Integer A, B, C, D
      total = 0.
      E = 1
      Integer Selection = 1
      total = Selection + 1
      Print *, 'Let''s do some math!!'
    *  16  continue
      Read(5, 65) A, B, C, D
  65  Format(I4, I4, I4, I4)
      write(6,66)
  66  Format(4(2x, I4))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have a declaration after an active statement.     That is what your compiler means by "Statement at (2) invalid in context established by statement at (1)".   So change the order of the statements.

Comment: Thank you so much... even my teacher I was wondering about that!! Thank you!! Thank you!!!